# Pass JSON object to jenkins as a parameter

Tags: json, jenkins

I want to pass JSON object as a parameter to Jenkins.

This is how i am currently running the pipeline

```
curl -i -X POST --user $JENKINS_USER:$JENKINS_TOKEN $JENKINS_JOB_URL/build --data-urlencode json@$JENKINS_PARAMETERS
```

where `JENKINS_PARAMETERS` is a JSON file.

```
    {
    "parameter": [{
            "name": "name",
            "value": "abc"
        },
        {
            "name": "age",
            "value": "40"
        },
        {
            "name": "country",
            "value": "xyz"
        },
        {
            "name": "address",
            "value": "qwerty"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, if one of the parameter itself has a JSON value, I'd need to pass it something like

```
{
    "parameter": [{
            "name": "name",
            "value": "abc"
        },
        {
            "name": "age",
            "value": "40"
        },
        {
            "name": "country",
            "value": "xyz"
        },
        {
            "name": "address",
            "value": "qwerty"
        }, {
            "name": "tree",
            "value": {
                "tree1": "branch1",
                "tree2": "branch2"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there something i can do on Jenkins side that I don't get the `tree` parameter as a string, Can i get it in its original form (`JSON`) so that i don't have to parse it in the groovy?

FYI: I am running the pipeline in sandbox mode

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That is exactly what [Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/generic-webhook-trigger) does.